# How to create a combined inbox in Outlook 2016 (IMAP / Exchange)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I have multiple emails in Outlook and I want to have all of my inboxes shown in one folder. This is possible while using POP3, but I haven't been able to find any ways to do this for IMAP and Exchange inboxes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[microsoft answers topic](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_outlook-mso_windows8-mso_365hp/combine-imap-inboxes-in-outlook/205d702d-9592-4a24-a86b-006911d9f0cf)

> it's not possible to combine the inboxes for IMAP accounts as the Change Folder-button doesn't exist for IMAP accounts. You also cannot select an existing data file when setting up an IMAP account like you can do for POP3 accounts.